# What possible factors could prevent or break Laravel array cast from functioning the way it ought to?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have been trying to get Laravel cast to work, but to no avail. Mind you, this is not the first time I am using the array casting on a project and that's why I am dumbfounded with the behavior I am getting from this scenario.

Here are the surrounding conditions that I believe should be enough to make array cast work

LARAVEL VERSION: v6.4.1

DATABASE ENGINE: MariaDB 10.3.21 (JSON columns were added at around 10.0.2)

MIGRATION

```
...
$table->json('link_details')->nullable()->after('link_box');
...
```

The above migration was made using the ...`:migration add_link_details_to_table` command cos i already created the table some migrations earlier.

MODEL

```
    protected $fillable = [
        ...'link_details',...
    ];

    protected $cast = [
        ...,
        'link_details' => 'array',
        ...
    ];
...
```

MODEL CONTROLLER (store method)

```
...
$data = [
  ...
];

$linkDetails = array('details1'=>$request['d1'],'details2'=>$request['d2']);

$package= Package::create($data);

$package->link_details = $linkDetails;
$package->save();

/*
To clarify, I had to take this approach of adding $linkdetails after Package is created to prevent certain errors. I also cant add it directly into $data from onset due to certain conditions. 
*/
...
```

On creating a new package, `link_details` column in database has record `{"details1":"some words","details2":"some more words"}`

ROUTE (api)

```
...
    Route::resource('pack', 'PackageController');
...
```

And to prevent issues with route model binding, i have the following in the boot method of my RouteServiceProvider.php

```
use App\Package;
...
Route::model('pack', Package::class);
...
```

**THE PROBLEM**

If i call the show method like 
`...api/package/23` 
where the show method is

```
    public function show(Package $package)
    {
        dd($package->link_details); //OR dd($package['link_details'])
    }
```

I get a result like this

```
"{"details1":"some words","details2":"some words"}"
```

Instead of

```
array:2 [
  "details1" => "some words"
  "details2" => "some more words"
]
```

As a result, I cannot access link details data using `$package->link_details->details1 //OR $package['link_details']['details1']`. Any attempt to do so leads to the following error

```
{
    "message": "Trying to get property 'details1' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/home/username/beta.address.com/app/Http/Controllers/CertainController.php",
    "line": 83,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/username/beta.address.com/app/Http/Controllers/CertainController.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
...
```

I have also compared the project with another recently completed project where I used the array cast system. Everything appears to be in other except the output when I try to access data in json database columns.

I have manually accessed the database and set it again to JSON column type (which is a form of LONGTEXT btw) and with no effect.

I have tried everything including trying to rollback everything I've to some days in the past using Version control, perhaps I might have installed or configured something to cause this. The behaviour turned out to still be the same.

Now I am left with doing a fresh Laravel installation and starting over, a route I cannot afford to tread at this point in time.

What could be the issue? Could it be something server related or just a mis-configuration somewhere.

**NOTE**
I have the following packages installed in my laravel app:

*spatie/laravel-medialibrary,
barryvdh/laravel-cors,
jeremykenedy/laravel-roles,
laravel/passport,
pragmarx/countries-laravel,
xeviant/laravel-paystack,
laracademy/generators*

Comment: `json_decode($package->link_details, true)` for `array`and `json_decode($package->link_details)` for `object`.

Comment: @user2094178 thanks for the suggestion but that defeats the whole point of the array cast system.

It means i have to do json decode anytime/anywhere i'm accessing a json column.

What i am looking for is why cast is not function or functioning in part.

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Could you inspect the database to see how the `link_details` are stored? It could be deserialized two times instead of one, which explains why it comes back as a json string instead of an array.